# How to optimize this mysql query?

Tags: mysql

I have this query

```
SELECT id FROM btn 
WHERE parentid =0
AND (mem_id =ANY(SELECT mem_id FROM network WHERE frd_id='401') || mem_id ='401')
ORDER BY btn.date DESC LIMIT 0,20
```

& this query

```
SELECT mem_id FROM net WHERE frd_id='401'
```

gives me result like this

```
mem_id
34
45
633
24
22
```

I want to optimize the above main query which is currently taking 46 second after scanning 13,373 records of `btn` table

Please suggest me hw can I optimize this query?

thnks

Comment: We can't really help without knowing your database structure.

Comment: Do you have any indexes at all? If yes, where? What is `EXPLAIN` showing?

Comment: `Field Type Null Key Default Extra
id  bigint(20)  NO  PRI  (NULL)  auto_increment`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.id FROM btn b
INNER JOIN network n ON (n.mem_id = b.mem_id)  
WHERE b.parentid = '0'
AND ('401' IN (n.frd_id, n.mem_id))
ORDER BY b.date DESC 
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

Make sure to have indexes on

```
btn.mem_id, btn.parentid, btn.date
network.mem_id, network.frd_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to index the values that you search on.  So, based on the two above:

```
parentid, frd_id, mem_id
```

That should help considerably...